# Build a dataframe from a filtered list of tuple

Tags: python, pandas

I have a two lists

```
kuid -> ['LOdRTFfn', 'Lckq4LkU', 'LcsYHodm']
```

And NN that is a list of tuple where the first element is a list of indexs of kuid and the other element is an array of values

```
NN -> [([0, 1, 2], [0.0, 1.2, 1.4]), ([1, 0, 2], [0.0, 1.4, 1.4]), ([2, 0, 1], [0.0, 1.1, 1.4])]
```

I'd like to keep only the indexes where the values are less then 1.3 for example:

```
[([0, 1], [0.0, 1.2]), ([1], [0.0]), ([2, 0], [0.0, 1.1])]
```

and then get the correct value of kuid and build a dataframe:

```
   kuid      la                    lametric                 
0  LOdRTFfn  [LOdRTFfn, Lckq4LkU]  [0.0, 1.2] 
1  Lckq4LkU  [Lckq4LkU]            [0.0]
2  LcsYHodm  [LcsYHodm, LOdRTFfn]  [0.0, 1.1]
```

Is it possible to do this with list of comprehensions (or other fast solution) avoiding looping? The array could be very large....

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way

```
In [1789]: df = pd.DataFrame(dict(kuid=kuid, NN=[np.array(x) for x in NN]))

In [1790]: df['lametric'] = df.NN.apply(lambda x: x[1][x[1] < 1.3])

In [1791]: df['la'] = df.NN.apply(lambda x: [kuid[int(i)] for i in x[0][x[1] < 1.3]])

In [1792]: df
Out[1792]:
                                   NN      kuid    lametric  \
0  [[0.0, 1.0, 2.0], [0.0, 1.2, 1.4]]  LOdRTFfn  [0.0, 1.2]
1  [[1.0, 0.0, 2.0], [0.0, 1.4, 1.4]]  Lckq4LkU       [0.0]
2  [[2.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.1, 1.4]]  LcsYHodm  [0.0, 1.1]

                     la
0  [LOdRTFfn, Lckq4LkU]
1            [Lckq4LkU]
2  [LcsYHodm, LOdRTFfn]
```